# Exact sequence of abelian groups, property transfers

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

We had the statement that with an exact sequence of multiplicatively written abelian groups
$U \mapsto V \mapsto W \mapsto X \mapsto Y$ and in $U$, $V$, $X$, $Y$ every group element has a unique $n$-th root ($n \in \mathbb{Z}$) That $W$ has this property as well.

How do I see that? Does it help me that the $n$ roots form a group under multiplication? Or why is that?
Any help/hint/tipp would be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raising to the $n$th power is a homomorphism of an abelian group to itself.  Apply the [five-lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma) to the commutative diagram consisting of two rows of your given exact sequence, where all of the vertical maps are raising to the $n$th power.